# Select tag with 1000 options - performance hit

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I am using a plugin called Chosen which basically adds searching to a select html object. 
I load the results from an ajax page.
However I have a lot of options appended to the select tag - around a thousand. 
Maybe it is the chosen plugin, but having a 1000 options does seem a bit laggy.

How is this gonna affect performance and what are the workarounds?

Comment: Can you show an example code on JSfiddle?

Comment: Do you actually have a problem or are you just wondering if there i going to be a problem?

Comment: Yes, it is laggy. That is the problem!!!!!

Comment: Did you try using select2 instead? we use it on a current project and it's pretty good, even with big amounts of data (http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/)

Comment: It looks exactly like chosen. Multiple select works in the same manner as well. When you say "big amounts of data" - how big were they? Somewhere in the thousands?

Comment: The way chosen works is that it loops through and parses the select tag, and then adds elements to the DOM including DIVs and SPANs to visually represent each option - and then hides the original select tag.  Looping 1000 options and writing that much to the DOM for each option in JS does seem heavy.   Searching in chosen iterates over the select -
Are you pulling from a DB?  can you incorporate the search on the DB side?

Comment: I am making a call to a php page, which prints back the data.

Comment: note: for 20k items I found select2 (3.3.2) to be slower than chosen (0.9.12). that said neither were very fast.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of `<select>` you could use `<input>` + `<datalist>`, that handles 1000+ options pretty well.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/klesun/mfgteptf/)

```
<input type="text" list="your-data-list"/>
<datalist id="your-data-list">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    ...
    <option value="9999">Option 9999</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: I am surprised how much faster this is than using SELECT.

Comment: Unfortunately it runs like absolute crap now on Chrome and locks up the tab on one meager scroll event.