# Passing a whole table to a blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table named `tags` which contains thousands of tags, and increasing. While creating a new post (via `newPost` blade), I want to pass all tags from controller into this blade and populate them in a dropdown list (with typing functionality) to help the user adding tags. I feel this will be a lot of data to be sent with every post creation, which would affect performance. Am I right ? Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes you're right but some thousands of tags could not be a problem if you are not adding a new post every few seconds. This is a basic and big question, every programmer has to deal with big data size in some part of their code and the solution depends a lot on the frequency of the requests. So don't overoptimize if you don't need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561200/select-tag-with-1000-options-performance-hit

Comment: I would suggest using ajax approach for this typeahead functionality. Start sending ajax requests (and also cancel previous ones) as user type. And maybe add at least 2 character requirement before sending requests, this way it creates a smooth typeahead experience and the method I prefer for tagging.